# Trying to build a history of popular laptop models

Tags: laptop, history

A requirement on a software project is it should run on typical business laptops up to X years old. However while given a specific model number I can normally find out when it was sold, I can't find data to do the reverse... for a given year I want to see what model numbers were released/discontinued.

We're talking big-name, popular models like Dell Latitude/Precision/Vostro, Thinkpads, HP, etc. The data for any model is out there but getting a timeline is proving hard. Sites like Dell are (unsurprisingly) geared around current products, and even Wikipedia isn't proving very reliable.

You'd think this data *must* have been collated by manufacturers or enthusiasts, surely?

**edit**: I suppose another way to phrase this, if the data doesn't exist in the form I want, is:

"*In each year 2005-2010, what are the typical low/mid-range business laptop/desktop models people would be buying*" - this goes for HP, IMB/Lenovo, etc too if anyone has that information... **maybe someone who works as an IT administrator might be able to pull up what your company was *buying* in each year**?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of ThinkPad models with release date and specifications: http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/ThinkPad_History

Comment: That's awesome, exactly the thing I'm trying to find... just for all mainstream manufacturers! Thanks!